# Xcode command line build and archive error

Tags: xcode, command-line, jenkins, calabash-ios

I am trying to build and archive project to create .ipa via commandline using below command

```
$ xcodebuild archive -project test.xcodeproj -scheme "Test" -archivePath /build
```

but it gives below error

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
Ld /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-gymccixkvyhthdhhxixgplbqdrhk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Test/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/test.build/Release-iphoneos/Test.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Test normal arm64

Ld /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-gymccixkvyhthdhhxixgplbqdrhk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Test/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/test.build/Release-iphoneos/Test.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Test normal armv7
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: It is solved now. i was giving path of .xcodeproj instead of .xcworkspace

Answer (score 0):

We need more information.  I suspect however, that /build is not a writeable directory.

For good example of how to build with scripts see this project:

https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app/blob/master/CalSmokeApp/Makefile